# Delete objects from s3 bucket before writing from Spark

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I want to delete all files under folder before start writing. In spark there is option of `Mode.Overwrite`, will this solve my problem I guess

Also, how does spark overwrite objects in s3? Does it use any aws services internally?

And what's a difference between using `Mode.Overwrite` or code (`https://gist.github.com/zhelyan/75f43b9b2613b887251961ac91940053`) for deleting objects before writing in s3?

Comment: @John Rotenstein, can you please share one this ?

Answer (score 0):

> how does spark overwrite objects in s3? Does it use any aws services internally?

yes, it is called "the S3 REST API"

The code snippet https://gist.github.com/zhelyan/75f43b9b2613b887251961ac91940053 is the basic algorithm. Sadly it would break in production as soon as you have more than 1000 entries to delete as that is the limit you can put in a single request. Even issuing a request for 1000 deletes is dangerous as that counts as 3500 of the Write ops s3 allows per second; there is a limit there of 3000/second in normal conditions and can sometimes get worse. S3 will respond to overload by sending a 503 "throttle" response back which simply causes the client to sleep for a few seconds and then post the same request -it doesn't fix throttling. See [HADOOP-16823
Large DeleteObject requests are their own Thundering Herd](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-16823) for this actually happening in production.

The result of a listObjects() call is also restricted to at most 1000 entries; on a versioned bucket with many overwritten files the list can actually time out, which is why the listObjectsV2() call is what AWS recommend. This can return fewer entries if it needs to, with a continuation flag.

Overall then: the example doesn't scale well enough, but enough to get you started.

What is needed for large production systems of many hundreds of thousands of entries is

- expect pages of LIST calls to come back
- as the listing comes in, issue DELETE calls but in a page size < 1000 to avoid throttling.
- do the delete and list in separate threads for better performance -they can both

Which is what the s3a delete() call ends up doing: https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/impl/DeleteOperation.java

It's still a pretty slow operation; there's some thought about having the s3a code issue > 1 smaller DELETE call in parallel for better performance [HADOOP-17881
S3A DeleteOperation to parallelize POSTing of bulk deletes](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-17881). However, do that and the probability of throttling increases a lot as well as interfering with other processes trying to write to the same bucket/ bucket partition. It'd have to include leaky-bucket rate limitation so that we could still restrict the number of write calls per second issued by the S3 a client without even waiting for 503 responses from S3 and the backoff/retry responses needed there. That is already done for bits of the azure ABFS client, so not impossible -just more work.

I think everyone would be happier if application code stopped needing to delete directory trees of data as part of their critical processing paths.